# How to toggle class in conditionally for a specific element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to toggle a class of an element only if its grandparent element has a specific class. The code is like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="active">
        <a class"something" href="#"><span class="icon-a"></span></a> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class"something" href="#"><span class="icon-a"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class"something" href="#"><span class="icon-a"></span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the jQuery code I have tried is:

```
if ($(".something span").parents('li').hasClass("active") && $(".something span").hasClass("icon-a")) {
$(".something span").toggleClass("icon-a").toggleClass("icon-b");
}
```

The problem is all the span elements got its class toggled. I only need to toggle if the grandparent element `<li>` has an "active" class.

Comment: What are you using that class for? If it's only for styling, couldn't you just create a CSS rule which does the grandparent detection and add the grandchild class freely?

Comment: What are you trying to create? You didn't specify how the class will be toggled. i.e: using `.click`

Comment: I need it when the page is load, so I put this inside $(document).ready(function()). I can't put it in the CSS as the CSS can't detect if the li element has "active" class or not.

Comment: Yes, CSS can do that. It can't add a class, but you can use the jQuery selector in my answer as a CSS selector and use that for CSS rules. No JavaScript required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the elements you mean, and forget about the conditional.

```
$('li.category.active > a.something > span.icon-a').addClass('icon-b');
```

Comment: I can't because this code will have both icon-a and icon-b classes shown up. I need to show icon-b only if the li element has "active" class.

Comment: @user2395853.. Just chain `removeClass('icon-a')` after the addClass

Comment: Thank you! It works! I put toggleClass though instead of addClass and removeClass.